# Invoking DOM Ready manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, document-ready

Is it possible to invoke DOM ready manually after the first DOM ready is executed, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Alohaaa!');
});

$(document).ready();
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to fill up the document with `document.write()` and then call DOM Ready again...

Comment: Use a callback function, ready handler is unbound once called

Comment: I don't think you can, because `ready` isn't actually some event type that is triggerable; it's treated specially (as a Deferred). Anyways, did you bother testing?

Comment: @Ian ya using promise and when done using this snippet to unbound handler: `jQuery( document ).trigger("ready").off("ready");`

Comment: i wish there were, and i'm hoping someone knows something, but AFAIK, you have to folk jQuery to collect the ready calls if you don't control all the scripts that use it.

Comment: @roasted I don't understand your point. You can't use `.trigger("ready")` because `ready` isn't an event (try it in a jsFiddle). And `.ready()` doesn't return the internal Deferred (for good reasons), so it can't be manually triggered

Comment: @Ian I don't know how to interpret this result: http://jsfiddle.net/MNA6B/ So we cannot trigger ready event bound using the shortcut alias 'ready' but we can if bound using the .on() method. As you can see there, the ready event is still fired when DOM is ready but no more once the DOM as finished to load (is effectively ready).

Comment: @roasted Of course, but using `.on()` and `.trigger()`, you're dealing with a custom event type you just made up (no different than mishik's answer below). Which is perfectly fine. But it's not the same as literally triggering the `ready` that we're talking about. I don't know if this helps understand: http://jsfiddle.net/MNA6B/1/

Comment: @Ian I still don't understand why in jquery source they still trigger any bound ready events? `if ( jQuery.fn.trigger ) {
   jQuery( document ).trigger("ready").off("ready");
  }`  Is it just to deal with specific case where .on() method is used? I'd really appreciate your feedback, thx.

Comment: @roasted Hmm very interesting. I didn't realize you were referencing actual jQuery source code. Well, I wonder if `ready` used to be an event type that jQuery supported, and this is their way of backward compatibility. I would guess it's before the use of a Deferred object (maybe not). But yeah, the `.off()` is definitely so it only fires once for existing handlers (obviously). But jQuery doesn't actually allow you to trigger the **real** `ready` event with `.trigger()` (per my last jsFiddle). Again I don't know if it helps, but http://jsfiddle.net/cJm9B/

Comment: @Ian Just checking the DOC concerning ready method and see that the `.on()` syntax is deprecated since jq 1.8. So ya, I assume you are right concerning backward compatibility. I should have read DOC firstly as usual, my bad... Thank you very much ;)

Comment: @roasted No problem, we both learned something new throughout all this :)

Answer (score 3):

No, not for this event. But you can do this:

```
$(document).on("mycustomevent", function() {
  alert("Alohaa!");
});
```

And then, whenever needed:

```
$(document).trigger("mycustomevent");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function myReadyFunction(){
    alert('ok');
}

$(myReadyFunction); //this is fired on document ready
```

Then call `myReadyFunction();` when you need.